# porque se pierde el valor de las variables de session al cambiar de controlador .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

estoy trabajando en Net Core, pero tengo problemas al Manejar datos en las Variables de Session, si cargo algun dato en una variable de Sesion en HomeController en la vista puedo acceder a el, pero cuando cambio de vista de otro Controller el dato de la var. de Sesion se pierde.

esto congire en el StartUp, metodo ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
        services.AddSession();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

en mi controlador lo cargo asi:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("User", "Juan");
```

en mi vista lo obtengo asi:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

    @{
        Layout = "_Layout";

        string h = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("User");

    }
```

Como les dije anteriormente en la vista del mismo controlador obtengo sin problema el valor de la sesion, pero cuando cambio de vista de otro controlador el valor se pierde, con Asp MVC no me pasaba esto, que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

Para persistir datos entre paginas usa `TempData["myvar"]="contenido"; TempData.Keep();// esto hace que el valor no se pierda.` espero que te sirva. Saludos

Comment: gracias ya lo solucione, pero me intereso tu sugerencia, pero algo no me quedo muy claro: si uso TempData["myvar"]="contenido" y quiero pasar de un controller a otro, la informacion se perderia, salvo que lo implemente asi:

TempData["myvar"]="contenido";
TempData.Keep();

eso es correcto?

Comment: Que bueno que lo solucionaste. Si asi es, ya que el método keep() hace que la información no se pierda. Saludos